# Access Azure DevOps YAML variables in Blazor server app?

Tags: azure-devops, blazor, blazor-server-side

If I have a yaml file and I set variables which are counters, how can I access that variable from Blazor Server?

I.e. my yaml may look like this:

```
variables:
  version.Major: '1',
  version.Minor: $[counter(variables['verion.Major'], 1)]
  version.Revision: $[counter(variables['verion.Minor'], 1)]
  versionName: '$(version.Major).$(version.Minor).$(version.Revision)']
```

And I'd like to access `versionName` from a Blazor Server component...

Comment: Hi, sorry. Yes, I solved it using that library which I found before your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to burn those variables into something that is part of the blazor app. There are many options:

- overwrite the assembly version
- add the values to the config file
- write the value into some other file
- set the value as a extended property of the deployment (in an Azure web app for example)

Comment: Yes, I'd like to pass versionName to appsettings.json. Are there any resources you know of for guidance on this?

Comment: You could use a bit of powershell to write the values into it, there are a number of tasks in the marketplace that can jsonpath values into a file and there are tasks that do token replacements.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-file-patch

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to work through ReplaceTokens marketplace right now

Comment: I saw your question pop up.

Answer (score 0):

> Access Azure DevOps YAML variables in Blazor server app?

Variables are affiliated products of Azure devops. We could not directly access these azure devops-specific products without the help of REST API.

To resolve this, the ReplaceToken task from the Marketplace https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens should be correct way.

[image]

Comment: Hi there. Yes, this works and writes to appsettings. But it only gets updated if there is an accompanying release. On the build, if I pull the branch on local host, I don't see the updated variable. Is this common?